# How do we handle webgl context lost event in Three.js

Tags: three.js, webgl

I want to handle a lost context event in Three.js. There is a nice documentation about that [here](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/HandlingContextLost) but unfortunately it doesn't work when I apply it to my `renderer.domElement`. I try to lose the context by clicking and some variable in `loseContext()` are undefined.

I guess the structure is different in Three.js. Any expert?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this about the renderer was initialized and assuming of course that the variable you stored the renderer into is named 'renderer'.

```
renderer.context.canvas.addEventListener("webglcontextlost", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // animationID would have been set by your call to requestAnimationFrame
    cancelAnimationFrame(animationID); 
}, false);

renderer.context.canvas.addEventListener("webglcontextrestored", function(event) {
   // Do something 
}, false);
```

BTW - loseContext is not defined by Three.JS and it isn't a standard method as of this time.  You can simulate it by doing the following.

Load this script before Three.JS

[https://github.com/vorg/webgl-debug](https://raw.github.com/tparisi/WebGLBook/master/Chapter%207/webgl-debug.js)

Then after you've started your renderer you can hook the loseContext to the canvas.

```
renderer.context.canvas = WebGLDebugUtils.makeLostContextSimulatingCanvas(renderer.context.canvas);
```

To trigger the loseContext you would do this.

```
renderer.context.canvas.loseContext();
```

And you can then also have it fail after a set number of calls by doing this.

```
renderer.context.canvas.loseContextInNCalls(5);
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how would you do this if you're not using Three.js. In other words, if you're using the raw WebGL API. Thank you.

Comment: While using `webgl-debug.js` with ThreeJS, I found that I had to manually call `renderer.context.canvas.getContext("webgl");` before using `renderer.context.canvas.loseContext();`

Comment: Context loss can be simulated in three.js like this: `renderer.context.getExtension('WEBGL_lose_context').loseContext();`

Comment: `gl.getExtension('WEBGL_lose_context').loseContext();` seems to work on any webgl2 context, three.js or not